# Trying to extract values from aws-cli response using jq but failing, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jq, json-query

I have the following json structure:

```
[
  {
    "IsDefault": false,
    "CidrBlock": "172.19.0.0/16",
    "DhcpOptionsId": "dopt-37fd70550",
    "State": "available",
    "CidrBlockAssociationSet": [
      {
        "CidrBlockState": {
          "State": "associated"
        },
        "CidrBlock": "172.19.0.0/16",
        "AssociationId": "vpc-cidr-assoc-f3c1559a"
      }
    ],
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "product-Production"
      }
    ],
    "InstanceTenancy": "default",
    "VpcId": "vpc-1f0e197d"
  },
  {
    "IsDefault": false,
    "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
    "DhcpOptionsId": "dopt-0a550861",
    "State": "available",
    "CidrBlockAssociationSet": [
      {
        "CidrBlockState": {
          "State": "associated"
        },
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
        "AssociationId": "vpc-cidr-assoc-8955dae0"
      }
    ],
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "Marketing VPC"
      }
    ],
    "InstanceTenancy": "default",
    "VpcId": "vpc-36b5585d"
  },
  .
  .
  .
]
```

I'm trying to print all VpcId's using jq but I can't find the right way to do it.

Here's what I've tried:

```
command | jq -r '.VpcId[]'
command | jq -r '.VpcId'
command | jq -r '.[] | .VpcId'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your third effort works for me, although I have to use double quotes since I'm on Windows.  What is the error you get for `.[] | .VpcId`?

Comment: jq: error (at <stdin>:154): Cannot index array with string "VpcId"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the command you are using is `aws ec2 describe-vpcs`.

This command actually returns the following structure:

```
{
    "Vpcs": [
        {
            "VpcId": "vpc-xxxxxxxx", 
        }
    ]
}
```

So you want to reach into the `Vpcs` key before you iterate over the array, Like this:

```
aws ec2 describe-vpcs | jq -r '.Vpcs | .[] | .VpcId'
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to consider would be to use `..`, e.g.

```
.. | .VpcId? // empty
```

will print the values of all "VpcId" keys, except for `null` and `false` values.

Incidentally, `.Vpcs | .[] | .VpcId` can be abbreviated to `.Vpcs[].VpcId`